# Convert column into the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

This is my current result set of my query:

```
Question   Sol25A   Sol25B   Sol25C   Sol40A   Sol40B
======================================================
A           1        4          2       6         0
B           2        3          2       1         9
C           6        7          1       0         8
======================================================
Total =    9         14         5       7         17
======================================================
```

And I want the result in this form:

```
Product   Total
===============
Sol25A      9
Sol25B      14
Sol25C      5
Sol40A      7
Sol40B      17
```

Can you please provide me the query for me, this will be the great help for me.

Comment: Better build query yourself and if it doesn't work, show us and let it fix then. SO is not code writing service.

Comment: UNION ALL with GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you unpivot using `cross apply` and then aggregate:

```
select product, sum(val)
from t cross apply
     (values ('Sol25A', Sol25A), ('Sol25B', Sol25B), ('Sol25C', Sol25C),
             ('Sol40A', Sol40A), ('Sol40B', Sol40B)
     ) v(product, val)
group by product;
```